# How to set localport for ssh tunneling in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ssh, tunneling, ssh-tunnel, eclipse-rse

I would like to connect to a remote server with ssh tunneling at someting like *localport*:server1.blabla.com:*remoteport* . I think i know how to set the the *remoteport* (select the 'sftp files' of the connection and change 'port' in the properties panel to *remoteport*), but i can't find how i can set *localport*. How should i take care of this?

Ps. i hope i didnt switch localport and remoteport since it is quite confusing to me. With *remoteport* i mean the port on the server i need to access, with *localport* i mean the port on my local computer i want to forward it to (and that can be chosen freely).